# Jquery Sort multiple Tbody

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table like this :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>100</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DTP</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>VTP</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RTP</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Testing</th>
            <th>100</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>QTP</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ATP</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CTP</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click department header, `tr` inside data and testing should get sorted. But data and testing `TH` should remain the same.

I don't want to use any jQuery plugin. Kindly share code to do this task.

Comment: sort according to? be specific.

Comment: Sort By asc or descending.

Comment: Data and Testing are sorted independently in each tbody?

Comment: But sort what? the Numeric values or QTP,ATP?

Comment: Yes. QTP , ATP numeric are independent. Data & Testing TH will remain Same. Only TR inside the Data & Testing will be sorted ie - Data - DTP,VTP,RTP and Testing - QTP,ATP,CTP will be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick implementation. Hopefully you will improve it and it will match your needs:

```
var $table = $('table'),
    $th = $table.find('thead th'),
    $tbody = $table.find('tbody');

$th.on('click', function() {

    $th.removeClass();

    var index = this.cellIndex,
        sortType = $(this).data('sort'),
        sortDir  = $(this).data('dir') || 'asc';

    $tbody.each(function() {
        $(this).find('tr').slice(1).sort(function(a, b) {

            var aText = $(a).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text(),
                bText = $(b).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text();

            if (sortDir == 'desc') {
                temp = aText;
                aText = bText;
                bText = temp;
            }

            if (sortType == 'string') {
                return aText.localeCompare(bText);    
            }
            else {
                return +aText - +bText;
            }
        })
        .appendTo(this);
    });

    $(this).data('dir', sortDir == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('sort-' + sortDir);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6uzVn/